# Как в цикле подставлять ссылку из переменной?

Tags: python, циклы, selenium

Я пишу первую мою программу на python + selenium.
Допустим мой код это:
Перейти на страницу
Найти элемент по ид и кликнуть по нему.

Как мне это сделать в цикл повторение при этом нужно постоянно менять ссылку из переменной.Ид элемента остаётся один и тот-же.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Вам обязательно помогут, но для этого вы должны предоставить то, что вы сделали, примеры кода, ошибки, которые вы получаете, описать что не получается относительно вашего решения. Такие вопросы как у вас очень общие и их не принято задавать здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time

def click_element(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("путь к драйверу")
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    

    driver.find_element_by_id("id элемента").click()
    # или можешь заюзать xpath driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath") я просто без понятия какие ссылки ты будешь кормить функции и будут ли они находиться по одному и тому же пути xpath, бывают сайте где class - всегда генерируется рандомно
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()        



if __name__ == "__main__":
    links = [твои ссылки]
    for link in links:
        click_element(link)
```